# Using `longtabu` and `tikz` together

Tags: tikz-pgf, longtabu

The following LaTeX file does not compile in neither `xelatex` nor `pdflatex` for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu, tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtabu}{X}
        Lorem Ipsum
    \end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Gives the following errors:

```
Latex Error: ./test.tex:8 Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Latex Error: ./test.tex:8 Missing \endgroup inserted.
Latex Error: ./test.tex:8 Missing } inserted.
```

Removing the `tikz` package resolves the issue. However, I need `tikz` in my actual (non-reduced) file. Changing the column type in the table from `X` to `l` also resolves the issue.

Is this a known incompatibility (can you reproduce it)? Are there any workarounds to use both `longtabu` with `X`-columns and `tikz` together?

Comment: That works fine, both on my local system with TeX Live 2020 and on Overleaf which has TL19.

Comment: Must be something with my setup then, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Be aware that tabu is broken and unsupported.  Read the readme here before continuing to use it https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu